# Qual a diferença entre as propriedades PATHS e MAP do RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Em teoria parece que as duas propriedades de configuração do [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) tem como foco a mesma ação.

Alguém sabe as diferenças de como ambas configurações funcionam?

**PATHS:**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'modulo': 'endereco/para/o/modulo'
  }
 });
```

**MAP:**

```
require.config({
  map: {
    '*': {modulo: 'endereco/para/o/modulo'}
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html):

A propriedade `paths` permite você mapear módulos que estão para outros locais que não a `URL` base do script.

Um dos usos indicados na [documentação](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks) é para *fallback*, isto é, permitir o uso do script a partir de um CDN em produção e a partir de uma URL local para desenvolvimento.

E exemplo é:

```js
requirejs.config({
    //To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports check.
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'lib/jquery'
        ]
    }
});

//Later
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
});
```

**Use para definir locais alternativos para o mesmo módulo.**

---

Por outro lado, a propriedade `map` permite que scripts (módulos) diferentes do mesmo projeto possam que requerem um terceiro módulo possam usar versões diferentes desse módulo.

Exemplo:

```js
requirejs.config({
    map: {
        'newmodule': {
            'foo': 'foo1.2'
        },
        'oldmodule': {
            'foo': 'foo1.0'
        }
    }
});
```

De acordo com a configuração acima, quando `newmodule` usar `require('foo')` ele irá receber `foo1.2.js`. Quanto `oldmodule` fizer o mesmo, ele irá receber `foo1.0.js`.

**Use para definir qual versão de um determinado módulo deve ser importada por cada módulo.**

Comment: Tua resposta ta mais clara que a documentação, obrigado.